# Finding my song's registration with a Performing Rights Organization

Tags: songwriting, publishing

So, many years ago, I entered a songwriting competition. As a prerequisite, I had to register my song with a PRO. I know I did it, but I don't remember which PRO --it was either ASCAP or BMI.

I don't remember any of the other details at this point, and I can't locate the paperwork I received back.

I'm looking to release this song now and I need to know:

1. Is there a way to find out where my song was registered and when? (is there an online search portal)
2. Does being registered limit what I can do with this song? Does it conflict with newer services like Soundrop or Bandcamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, try the [BMI Repertoire Search](https://repertoire.bmi.com/StartPage.aspx) page. A brief test indicates they list the current PRO affiliation even if not BMI.

In the case of Bandcamp, there do not appear to be any restrictions from the Bandcamp camp. Here is their [terms of use page](https://bandcamp.com/terms_of_use).

On the BMI website, I did not immediately find their legalese, but their [FAQ page](https://www.bmi.com/faq) is worth a browse. A general site search for "bandcamp" brought up quite a few pages of artists who included their bandcamp pages, so at that level, it seems like people do both.

Comment: Does that mean you found it?